# Why does .NET's RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes method assign its results to a byte array parameter instead of returning a new byte array?

Tags: .net, random, cryptography, api-design

The .NET Framework has the [`RandomNumberGenerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator?view=netframework-4.8) class for generating cryptographically-secure random bytes. One of its main methods, [`GetBytes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator.getbytes?view=netframework-4.8), has the signature `void GetBytes (byte[] data)` - it takes a byte array as a parameter and fills it with random bytes, rather than returning a byte array. Why is this? Are there security reasons for operating on an existing array instead of creating a new one?

Comment: Most likely this is just for efficiency reason. If you use this method multiple times you can re-use the byte array and don't have to allocate and free the byte array memory again and again. You can also see this on other methods that output a byte array.

Comment: It might also be just a bad copy from e.g. the Java JCA framework (a lot of things can be seen as copies of ideas from the Java frameworks after all - and Java of course copied some things from C / C++). The problem with these questions is that the *why* question can only really be answered by the original authors. We can only try and find objective reasons that *could* indicate why.

Comment: Yeah, "why" questions are always at least a little tricky - I was mainly wondering if there's some security issue with allocations or something, which would be objectively apparent without asking the original creators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think security could be really the reason for the `byte[]` parameter in a managed framework. I don't see any difference with it being generated by the method and outside of it, as a `byte[]` - an array of a base type - is not likely to have multiple implementations. If there would be difference possible then it would make more sense to have the method generate the byte array.

Without it, the efficiency reason already given makes more sense; the byte array may be larg(-ish) after all, and you cannot duplicate the efficiency of the call that takes the bytes. There is also another method [that additionally takes an offset and "count" of bytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator.getbytes?view=netframework-4.8#System_Security_Cryptography_RandomNumberGenerator_GetBytes_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_) to an existing array. This lets you directly generate bytes to an array that can also hold other data (e.g. a concatenation of IV and ciphertext in a byte array). Of course the single parameter is just a special case / convenience method for that call. The multi-parameter one is the most important one for efficiency as you would otherwise have to duplicate the ciphertext as well; arrays cannot be shrunk after all. It would be strange to create a method with the same name but with a very different method signature.

Other frameworks such as the Java JCA have the same methods for `SecureRandom`. So it is likely that the authors knew about such frameworks and decided to mimic these existing API's, unless there was sufficient reason for change.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! I'll leave this open for a day, but if no better answers come along, expect a green checkmark tomorrow.

Comment: One difference is that by accepting (vs returning) an array allows the caller to pin the memory (GCHandle or `fixed`) before the call, avoiding the risk of GC compaction residuals. Not that it probably matters much here.

Comment: Ah, OK, so there *are* some possibilities for `byte[]` here :) interesting.